# How can I uninstall Apple's MacOS /System/Applications like TV, Music, Find My, Stocks on macOS macOS v10.15 (Catalina)?

Tags: catalina

I tried uninstalling them from LaunchPad, but it was not possible.

I tried deleting them from `/Applications` directory, it won't show the menu operation to "Move to bin".

I tried `sudo rm -rf /System/Applications/TV.app`, operation not permitted. I tried running `chown` and `chgrp`, it won't allow me to edit them at all.

Is there a way I can delete Apple's applications in `/System/Applications/` which I don't use at all?

Comment: You can‘t (easily),  it it‘s probably not worth it diskspace-wise. And they get reinstalled with the next update anyway.

Comment: Can we at least remove them from the Launchpad? I also get annoyed by icons I never used like the TV or Stocks I never use (and never will)